# Submitting a task from inside celery worker task body

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I have a celery worker, where processing function (alpha_task) is defined. I'd like to submit another job to celery workers from INSIDE this function body (alpa_task). The new job will be responsible for processing just computed result.

So simply saying, i want the result to processed by another pool of celery workers.
One pool is responsible performing the job and another for processing results.

Celery Worker -> Submit job for result processing -> Another Celery Workers

I was thinking to use different routing key and queue, so the worker will NOT have the result processing job  submitted to themselfs, but it doens't appear to work.

1. I have a following code for celery worker.

`app = Celery('celery_worker_A', backend='backendstring', broker='brokerstring')`

`@app.task
   def process_alpha_task(json_input):
     processor = TaskProcessor()
     r = processor.process(json_input)
     app.send_task('process_result', args=[r], kwargs={},queue='queue_result_processing', routing_key='key_result_processing')`

The problem is that the newly submitted task is being sent to same worker which just procesed "alpha" task, and i'm getting error about undefined task called "process_result" which is of course true.

I even tried to run this celery worker with forced queue, so it doesn't poll for any other tasks than alpha_tasks.

`celery -A proj worker -Q alpha_tasks.`

But it still seems to submit task to themselfs and poll for it, even though i defined other queue in send_task() and routing keys.

How can i achieve my goal, to process results using different celery workers?

//Edit:

I have one more example, should be more clear.

Explicitly running worker to process tasks ONLY from task_processor queue:

`celery worker -A task_processor -Q task_processor`

```
task_processor.py

app = Celery('task_processor', backend=config.get('CELERY', 'backend'), broker=config.get('CELERY', 'broker'))

#submit new task and route to resultprocessor queue, Shouldn't be processed by this worker.
def test():
    app.send_task('process_result', args=["ABC"], kwargs={}, queue="resultprocessor", routing_key="resultprocessorkey")

#TASK ROUTED CORRECTLY on worker start, NOT SUBMITTED TO THEMSELFS
test()

@app.task
def process_task(json_input):
    print("Processing task")
    #TASK ROUTING FAILED WHEN CALLED INSIDE BODY OF TASK, SUBMITTING TO THEMSELFS.
    test()
    print("Submitted request to  process result")
```

Comment: can you set your routing in [celery app config](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing)? My guess is that the automatic routing is not working because you don't create a task using that queue until within a task, when the app has already been initialized.

Comment: Hmm i tried but it didn't work. I've edited post with more clear example where it shows that when called from inside task body, the task is routed incorrectly, but from outside of task body it's all ok...

Comment: Nevermind i had a typo and got lost through all of these queues. It works correctly.